# A function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is differentiable if and only if its components are differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

I have a function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ and need to prove that it's differentiable if and only if its component functions are differentiable. The definition I'm working with is far different from what I'm used to, however. If $f$ is differentiable at some point $c$, then there exists a linear map $T$ such that
\begin{align*}
\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{|f(c + h) - f(c) - Th|}{|h|} = 0.
\end{align*}
The definition I have seen before excludes the norm in the numerator, and it's easy to expand $f$ out in terms of its components and combine it with the length $\frac{1}{|h|}$. With this norm, I can't figure out how to proceed.

Comment: If you remove the norm in the numerator, you need $\mathbf{0}$ rather than $0$ as the limit.  But they are equivalent results as  $|\mathbf{0}| =0$

Answer (score 2):

Your idea is fine, because $\text{something} \to 0$ iff $|\text{something}| \to 0$.